# Mockito - Mocking Concrete Classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Given the following code:

```
    LinkedList list = mock(LinkedList.class);
    doCallRealMethod().when(list).clear();
    list.clear();
```

by executing this test, a NullPointerException is thrown from first line in LinkedList#clear:

```
public void clear() {
    Entry<E> e = header.next;
    while (e != header) {
        Entry<E> next = e.next;
        //Code omitted.
```

but **header** has been instantiated before:

```
private transient Entry<E> header = new Entry<E>(null, null, null);
```

Could someone please explain what's happening during mock creation?

**#######  UPDATE.  ######**

Having read all answers especially Ajay's one, I looked into Objenesis source code and find out that it's using Reflection API to create the proxy instance (through CGLIB) and therefore bypassing all constructors in the hierarchy until java.lang.Object.

Here is the sample code to simulate the issue:

```
public class ReflectionConstructorTest {

    @Test
    public void testAgain() {

        try {
            //java.lang.Object default constructor
            Constructor javaLangObjectConstructor = Object.class
                    .getConstructor((Class[]) null);
            Constructor mungedConstructor = ReflectionFactory
                    .getReflectionFactory()
                    .newConstructorForSerialization(CustomClient.class, javaLangObjectConstructor);

            mungedConstructor.setAccessible(true);

            //Creates new client instance without calling its constructor
            //Thus "name" is not initialized.
            Object client = mungedConstructor.newInstance((Object[]) null);

            //this will print "CustomClient" 
            System.out.println(client.getClass());
            //this will print "CustomClient: null". name is null.
            System.out.println(client.toString());

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


class CustomClient {
    private String name;

    CustomClient() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " - Constructor");
        this.name = "My Name";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reasoning is flawless.
The key issue is that you are not operating on the actual `LinkedList` object.  Here is what is happening behind the scenes:

The object that you are given by Mockito's `mock()`  is an [Enhancer](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/cglib/Enhancer.html) object from the CGLIB library.

For me it is something like `java.util.LinkedList$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$cae81a28`

which kind of acts like a Proxy, albeit with the fields set to default values. (null,0 etc)

Comment: you are right but the exception is thrown from real object. even by debugging i can reach to real method. my question is if there is a real "LinkedList" object behind scene, then it's internal state should be ok too.

Comment: The reason why you are able to refer to the mocked object with a LinkedList reference means that the mocked object is a subclass of LinkedList. Hope that helps.

Comment: Even if the mock object is a subclass of Linkedlist, in order to create this subclass object, you need to create parent class object. (on of the parent constructors should have been called)

Comment: @AjayGeorge Even if the exception is thrown from the real code, the instance is still a Mockito mock, and Mockito is using tricks (via Objenesis) to bypass the default constructor of any mocked object (in order to be able to mock types with a private constructor). Also a mock will **never** initialize fields, because it shouldn't have to. What you want to achieve is a partial mock, you can do that via a [`spy`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T)). Also note that partial mocks usually indicates there is a design flaw in the tested code.

Comment: Also you can use delegation since 1.9.5, which is different from a spy : or via [`AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo()`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#delegatesTo(java.lang.Object))

Comment: This was just an example to find what's happening behind the scene. I'm familiar with spy and other possible alternatives. Maybe I should look at objenesis to find out the trick

Answer (score 9):

You are only asking Mockito to call the real thing on clear, the underlying object is still a fake created by Mockito for you. If you need a real LinkedList then just use the LinkedList - only the most heated purist of BDD would tell you to mock everything around you. I mean, you are not mocking Strings are you?

Mockito author himself has said that calling the real thing should be used scarcely, usually only for testing a legacy code.

If you need to spy on the real object (track the invocations) then Mockito has a feature for this too:

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = spy(list);
```

With spy, you can still stub a method if you need. It basically works like a mock, but isn't ;)

Comment: That's true, but doesn't answer the question. Outside the fact, that it is a not so good idea to do this, still we can figure out why the exception happens, don't we? Vlad gives the explanation, +1 for him.

Comment: As I've sad: you are only asking Mockito to call the real thing on clear, the object itself is not instantiated, mockito creates a fake for you underneath it. I've revised the answer to make it more clear. I will try to be more explicit the next time.

Comment: No offense :) Just wanted to point out, that sometimes, there are answers not answering the question but questioning the OP's course of action. And these are sometimes downvoted for doing so. I found it a good practice in the answer to first tell the OP why it is not working what he does (and thus answering the question) and then suggesting an alternative, if I have one to offer. After your edit, +1 for you, too.

Comment: This is a very valid remark - I have just assumed that "you are only asking Mockito to call the real thing on clear" implies that nothing else is real with that object. Nonetheless, a very good point, this wasn't clear at all :)

Comment: @theadam: you mentioned that the code is calling the real thing on method clear. how come the method is real but the object is fake?

Comment: I'd have to check this, but it is either a subclass of LinkedList with all fields set to null / 0 / other default value or it is an object with bytecode modified by CGLib.

If you really need to investigate on the LinkedList then you may create a spy on it with Mockito - it uses the whole real object but spies the invocations.

Updated my answer with this info.

Answer (score 1):

When you mock a class the object you are using is a fake, therefore the variables are not instantiated and the methods don't work as expected. You could use reflection to set a value for the header but I really wouldn't recommend this. As theadam said, the best thing to do would be to just use a list.